Building vs. technique - How or which to choose?
Right now we have building, which says If your question is about building techniques, this is the tag for you.
But we also have technique, which says Tricks and methods used to build models.
So right now, they're exactly the same thing - building techniques vs. techniques for building.
Which of these tags do we want to be the "right" one?
Or if we keep both, what's the difference between them? What's an example of a question that's about building but not technique, and one that's about technique but not building?

Building
"Technique" is a really vague, almost meta word. Technique for what? Techniques for applying stickers? Techniques for sorting? Techniques for cleaning? What question isn't a technique question?
Well, no, we mean exclusively techniques for building. So let's just use that.
I would even push for a more limited definition of building to mean mostly structural elements, perhaps opposed to decoration with color or lighting, or the software aspects of mindstorms programming.

All those questions that were tagged [tag:trivia] aren't [tag:technique] questions ;) but yes, that's why I've proposed we make [tag:technique] a synonym of [tag:building]

I actually proposed that we move technique to a synonym of building on the 8/11 - but the whole issue around voting for synonyms makes it very hard to get these accepted at the moment:
Please vote on synonyms (up if you think they are right, down if not), and you're able to:

Visit the proposed Synonyms page
Click through to the "Master" tag synonym page
Attempt to vote on the synonym.

The most likely result is:

Error: You do not have the required score on this tag to vote for this tag synonym - you need to have at least a score of 5 upvotes in the master tag to vote on that synonym.

The least likely result is:

Success: your vote is counted, and 3 other people also need to vote on it. 


I don't think tag synonyms are necessary at this point in the site (I also don't think they're bad, so keep on suggesting them and people should vote on what they can - it's just not much yet). There's only nine questions with the [tag:technique] tag, if we want it gone, let's just make it gone.
